# On Tychonoff's theorem

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $x_n:[0,1]\rightarrow E$ a sequence of applications, where $E$ is a normed space. Suppose that for every $t\in [0,1]$ $$\left \{ x_n(t):\;  n\in \mathbb N\right \} \text{ is weakly compact.}$$

> **Claim:** By [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Tychonoff%27s%20theorem%20states,respect%20to%20the%20product%20topology.), one can get that:
>
> $$\left \{ x_n(.):\;  n\in \mathbb N\right \}=\prod_{t\in [0,1]} \left \{ x_n(t):\;  n\in \mathbb N\right \}$$
> is weakly compact in $\mathcal{A}([0,1],E)$, where $\mathcal{A}([0,1],E)$ is the space of application from $[0,1]$ to $E$.

**Problem**: The left side of the equality is a subset of $\mathcal{A}([0,1],E)$, while the right side is a subset of $\{x_n([0,1]): n\in \mathbb N\}$!

I know the following application is bijective $$\begin{matrix}
\Phi: \mathcal{A}([0,1],E)& \rightarrow & E^{[0,1]}\\ 
x &\mapsto &  \big(x(t)\big)_{t\in [0,1]}
\end{matrix}$$

but I don't know how to use it, if its homeomorphism my problem will be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side (by the **definition** of an infinite product) is also in $\mathcal{A}([0,1],E)$.

Your $\Phi$ is the identity. There is nothing to prove.

IMO, it's the notation $\{x_n(\cdot): n \in \Bbb N\}$ that's strange.

Comment: This notation $\left \{ x_n(.) :\:n\in \mathbb N \right \} $ is exactly $\left \{ x_n:[0,1]\rightarrow E:\:n\in \mathbb N  \right \} $.